# Store dynamic values in a data structure

Tags: python, dictionary, global, persist

I have some text which is stored in an array 'A' (global data structure) whenever I run my program.

Now, the next time I run the same program, I want to append new text to the same array 'A'.

Eg: 1st time I run the program, the input values (1,12,32) are added into the array A, next time I run the same program with input values (18,7,92) .. I want the resulting array to be [1,12,32,18,7,92]

So essentially each time I run the program, new input data should be appended to that global Array.

How can I achieve this ?

Thank You.

Comment: Won't you need to persist the data outside your program? i.e. in a text file for instance.

Comment: @April Denver: almost similar to what I'm looking for.

Comment: @EdChum: what if I don't want to persist mydata outside the program ?

Comment: @AlekhyaVemavarapu how do you expect state to persist outside of a program?

Comment: @EdChum I didn't get you. I am asking, what if I don't want my data to be stored outside my program ? Is there a way where I can use a data structure (like something beyong 'global') to store it all ?

Comment: @AlekhyaVemavarapu you mean just store data where the lifetime is tied to the program? You can use whatever data structure you want, the point being that the data is gone once the program ends unless you persist it externally and reload it. Also `global` just refers to the scope of the variable, it isn't a data structure type

Comment: @EdChum Makes sense EdChum, Thanks for the insight.

Comment: @EdChum agreed, yes I know global is not a data structure type. I am referring to the scope itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use [**`pickle`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#module-pickle) module:

```
import pickle
data = [int(el) for el in raw_input().split()]
try:
    new = pickle.load(open("save.p", "rb")) + data
except IOError:
    new = data
pickle.dump(new, open("save.p", "wb"))
print pickle.load(open("save.p", "rb"))
```

Comment: Hi, out of curiosity, what makes pickle different from storing in .txt files

Comment: ahh, answered while I was typing... +1

Comment: @AlekhyaVemavarapu it implements serializing and de-serializing a Python object structure. So you don't care about formatting and reading your file

Comment: Okay, in that case, how is it better in terms of complexity(time & space) when you compare with .txt files ?

Comment: @user3990145 Thank YOU

Answer (score 1):

I would look into [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html), this way your data structure will remain as a python type, rather than parsing a plain text file.

```
import pickle
import sys

new_array = map(int, sys.argv[1:])

try:
     with open("datafile", "r") as fin:
         old_array = pickle.load(fin)
except IOError:
    # File doesn't exist
    old_array = []

with open("datafile", "w") as fout:
    pickle.dump(old_array + new_array)
```

Note that this is going to try to convert any command line arguments to `int`s (I did this because your examples only included `int`s).

Answer (score 0):

Simple, you need to open the file in a `append` mode this way

```py
file_ = open("MyFile.txt",'a')

input_ = whatever
file_.write(input)
```